# Meaning of "knocked him down in the kennel" (London 1818)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I having hold of him all the while; he then began striking me as hard as he could in my face, with both hands, and I was obliged to let go to defend myself; **I knocked him down in the kennel**, and as he endeavoured to get up, I made a grasp to lay hold of him again; he got from under my arm, and ran down Holborn; I pursued ... source; Old Baily records online.

Comment: That's it? You're not going to tell us anything else about where you found this? (I don't know what "Old Baily records online" means.) Or why you're confused?

Comment: "kennel" is an old word for "gutter" (related to "channel")

Comment: @J.R.  It's the records of criminal proceedings in the [Old Bailey](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oldbaileyonline.org%2F&ei=SzKcUJD4HcHlqgG7lYGYBA&usg=AFQjCNGRGlHmpJDRtc_74kE-dugMkdwzqQ&sig2=q394IutBUtLXYfaGtskTqg). Fascinating reading.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm sure you've got it. So if you're not going to vote to close as Too Localised (I'm not) you should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: Here's a couple more instances of ["knocked him down in the kennel"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22knocked+him+down+in+the+kennel%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) from Google Books, so it isn't (or at least, *wasn't*) that much of an unusual thing to say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you wish. But it's probably GR - the first two onine dictionaries I checked give it.

Comment: @StoneyB: I never know where to draw the line with things like this. But my rule of thumb is that if I know the answer already, ***and*** I can find confirmation of what I think in the first few "snippet view" entries returned by an obvious Google search term, it might well be GR. Otherwise, probably not. In this case I didn't know it; hence my abstention from closevoting for either reason.

Answer (score 6):

*Kennel* is an old word (an alternative spelling of *cannel*, cognate with *channel*) for *gutter*, a channel provided along a street to drain rainwater.

Just for grins, *OED 1* offers some useful phrases using *kennel*

- kennel wits, muddy brains
- kennel-nymph, a girl of the streets
- kennel-raker, a scavenger, a term of abuse.

Comment: *kennel-nymph?* Garrggghhhh! OED's cited *1771 Smollett Humph. Cl. 10 June, Let. i, He‥indulged himself‥with one of the *kennel-nymphs.* (and cross-references to the same) seem to be just about the only instances in Google Books. That particular one is *definitely* Too Localised for me!